# In microsoft Internet explorer when using input controls. It gives the resize options when we click instead of input field editable property

Tags: tinymce

When we try to use TinyMce with the input type controls like textbox, checkbox and etc. We get the resizable option when we click on the field. Instead of input field properties.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG2Is.png) It is showing like image 1.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBAb8.png) This is how we want to display.

Answer (score 1):

with the resizable option that is appearing, if you're using a  tag to add the textbox inside the editor, you can set a textbox [to be non-resizable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) with `resize: none;` in your CSS:

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

If you can share the tinymce.html file you are testing out the textbox input type with, we can try and solve why you're getting the resize option on focus instead of the input.